# Why CSS hover use a lot of CPU when I have a lot of DOM nodes

Tags: javascript, html, css, performance

I have an application that creates a lot of DOM Nodes (it starts with 2k DOM Nodes) when using it like Elementor, when I use it for a long time (when I reach 50k DOM Nodes) I see that the hover styles are laggy and the CPU usage goes up (on Chrome Performance Monitor) when I hover on elements that have hover styles.

The hover rule is:

```
.element {
  background-color: white;
  transition: all .3s;
}
.element:hover {
  background-color: #ddd;
}
```

How can I improve the performance?

Thanks

Edit:

I disabled the hover rule (background-color: #DDD and transition: all .3s) but I still see the CPU usage goes up...

Edit 2:
The CPU usage goes up not just on this element, any other element I hover is slow and laggy ...

Comment: If I have to guess it's due to the transition property (animation). can you test it without the transition property?

Comment: I just tried to disable both the CSS rule and the transition, and it stills bumps the CPU usage on hover over elements.

Comment: It's probably just the DOM tree then. 50K is a lot of nodes

Comment: Are there any other hover styles that are inherited from surrounding elements? It might stack up pretty quickly.

Comment: The hover state “bubbles up”, same as the majority of JS events do. If you hover one element, that automatically means hovering its parent as well. And the parent of that parent … Now depending on the nesting level (rather than the sheer number of elements alone), this could mean a lot of work for the browser, checking on _every level_ whether a different styling _might_ apply now.

Comment: @JWGeertsma No, It's one simple rule background-color: #DDD, the surrounding elements don't have hover state

Comment: Note: the CPU usage goes up not just on this element, any other element I hover is slow and laggy ...

Comment: @CBroe yes I have quite a lot of HTML nesting, the element I tried to hover on, has a depth of 9th from the <body>

Comment: @Atif when I create new DOM Nodes I delete them when I don't need them, but the garbage collector still hold them in memory I think, I tried both HTMLElementNode.remove() and HTMLElementNode = null, it reduced the issue but I still have performance issues.

Comment: The performance is perfectly fine without your CSS snippet? Can you create a [minimal example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) with jsfiddle, CodePen or similar?

Comment: @PeterKrebs it turns out that the issue is not CSS, it's like Atif said, it's DOM nodes issue, I have a lot of DOM Nodes ...
Unfortunately, the app is quite big (more than 1 year of work), If I have to create a minimal example it may take a considerable amount of time...

Comment: You made the thousands of DOM nodes by hand? You can create a minimal example with `for()` loops to create as many example nodes as you need.

Comment: Not by hand, they were created from JS.
The problem is from a library that I was using not the DOM Nodes, it wasn't resetting the event listeners and they kept stacking ...
I had to re-init them manually
Thanks for the help ✌

Answer (score 0):

The problem is from a library that I was using not the DOM Nodes, it wasn't resetting the event listeners, and they kept stacking ...
I had to re-init them manually.

Thanks for the help ✌